# In KDE System Monitor, why the application-specific network measurements may be missing?

Tags: kde, plasma5, bandwidth

There are two systems running Plasma 5.27.7: Debian testing and openSUSE Tumbleweed.

Under openSUSE, System Monitor tracks application-specific network activity, see screenshot:
[image: System Monitor showing app-specific network activity]
Under Debian, there are no Download/Upload columns (even in the "Configure columns..." list); the app-specific network chart is present but completely dead.

Why could these features be missing/inactive on Debian?

The versions of System Monitor are also 5.27.7.

Comment: I'm seeing the same with Kubuntu (5.27.4) and Fedora (5.27.6). Only thing I can think of is Debian is using different compile options.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Do you think those might be Plasma-wide compile options or specifically for System Monitor?

Comment: My guess would be for System Monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out with some help from KDE devs.

Library doing the work for the System Monitor: [libksysguard](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/libksysguard).

[Commit that adds per-process network information](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/libksysguard/-/commit/1bb5880f08e93e49017dfca6359b293a3bb6f5dc). Side note: 2019, so it's hardly a freshly baked thing trying to get on its feet right now.

Commit includes some conditional config operations, depending on `Libcap_FOUND`, on the `ksgrd_network_helper` executable. Do I have this executable in my system? I don't. Was it completely skipped by Debian building the binaries, possibly?

[Debian build log for libksysguard (4:5.27.8-1) on amd64](https://buildd.debian.org/status/fetch.php?pkg=libksysguard&arch=amd64&ver=4%3A5.27.8-1&stamp=1694649010&raw=0).

No, it wasn't skipped. Package `libkf5sysguard-bin` should put it into `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/ksysguard/ksgrd_network_helper`.

Do I have the package `libkf5sysguard-bin`? I don't o_O .

So the fix is simply `apt install libkf5sysguard-bin`. Both columns and the chart now work.

Now, why wasn't it installed along with all the other KDE stuff? That's a separate rabbit hole with package dependencies... First shot shows that only 2  packages even mention it (both missing on my system):

```
$ apt-cache rdepends libkf5sysguard-bin
libkf5sysguard-bin
Reverse Depends:
  libkf5sysguard-dev
  libksignalplotter9
```

Not sure where this leads, but the original question is now answered.