# On Debian trixie, why isn't libkf5sysguard-bin installed together with all the other KDE stuff?

Tags: debian, kde

Related: [In KDE System Monitor, why the application-specific network measurements may be missing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754309/in-kde-system-monitor-why-the-application-specific-network-measurements-may-be/)

KDE System Monitor on Debian trixie is missing a nice feature of per-app network stats due to package `libkf5sysguard-bin` not being installed automatically.

What could be the Debian reasons for omitting it by default?

What would be the correct entry point for asking Debian devs/maintainers to include it into the default KDE installation?

Comment: Why does it NEED to be in the default KDE installation? I use plenty of packages that are not part of the default installation ... I remedy that by *installing them* - because I realise that my requirements for Linux aren't the same as every other person using it, so, have to take the time to set up my system as I want it - this could take several minutes! But, at least the default installation isn't full of crap I don't need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know why it’s omitted by default, but if you want that to change, the best way is to submit a bug report:

```
reportbug libkf5sysguard-bin
```

Follow the prompts; the appropriate severity is “wishlist”. Make sure to explain why you think it would be useful to have this package installed by default with KDE (essentially your second paragraph).