# In Fedora 38, why doesn't ksgrd_network_helper have cap_net_raw, for per-app network stats in KDE System Monitor to work?

Tags: fedora, kde

Related:

- [In KDE System Monitor, why the application-specific network measurements may be missing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754309/in-kde-system-monitor-why-the-application-specific-network-measurements-may-be/)
- [On Debian trixie, why isn't libkf5sysguard-bin installed together with all the other KDE stuff?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758964/on-debian-trixie-why-isnt-libkf5sysguard-bin-installed-together-with-all-the-o)

KDE System Monitor per-app network stats don't work in Fedora 38 out of the box, too. The reason is different from Debian, though: `ksgrd_network_helper` is present but missing the required capability `cap_net_raw`.

Thus, to make it work: `setcap cap_net_raw+ep /usr/libexec/ksysguard/ksgrd_network_helper` from root. The setting survives reboots.

Is this a Fedora package setup bug? To me it looks like it simply forgets to set up the capability after package installation, but maybe I miss some reasoning here.

If this is a bug, what's the correct entry point for reporting it?